# How to list from higher numbers to lowers ones in php?

Tags: php

Say I have a variable like this:

```
$votes
```

That variable will store positive and negative numbers: -1, 0,  2, 3, etc...)

How to code a function that arrange those numbers but higher ones to lower ones?

Comment: `$votes` is a variable or array? Could you make it clear?

Comment: @Gaurav: True, I meant a fitting one of those: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a string, use [explode](http://nl.php.net/explode), then [sort](http://nl.php.net/sort). If it's already an array, just use sort:

```
$votes = '-1, 0, 2, 3';
$votes = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $votes ) );
rsort( $votes, SORT_NUMERIC );
var_dump( $votes );

// or, if it's already an array:
$votes = array( -1, 0, 2, 3 );
rsort( $votes, SORT_NUMERIC );
var_dump( $votes );
```

*EDIT*; Changed sort to rsort, as it's highest to lowest, not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple:

```
$votes = array(-1, 0, 2, 3);
$votes = rsort($votes);

print_r($votes);
```

see: http://php.net/rsort

Answer (score 1):

`echo implode(', ', rsort($array));`  // if its an array

or

`echo implode(', ', rsort(explode(',', $array)));`   // if its a string

Answer (score 1):

If `$votes` is an array, just do:

```
rsort($votes, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

If it's a comma-delimited string, first `explode` it

```
$arr = explode("," $votes);
rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```